# How to import an default exported object containing functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If one file has an export default:

```js
export default {
   function,
   function2
}
```

How can I import these two functions in a separate file? When I try restructuring it with

```js
import { function, function2 } from 'path'
```

I get an error saying function is not exported from 'path'

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a default export, you will have to do it like below

```js
export default {
   function1,
   function2
}

import Path from 'path';

Path.function1();
Path.function2();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into [this](https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910) ressource.

Basically, you can achieve this, by writing:

```
export const myExport1 = function
export const myExport2 = function2
```

And then:

```
import { myExport1, myExport2} from 'path'
```